# How to flip a card with cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I need to flip a card to see its back, then side and then front gradually with animation like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=te0Je0y4zU0 . How I can do this with cocos2d-x? I have took a look on `OrbitCamera` and `RotateBy in 3D` tests. They are very close to the one I want to, the only problem is that when the sprite turns around I see not the back (as at should be another texture, but the same spite from back camera). I understand that I should use 2 sprites to get the effect, but how I should do that, I don't know. Should I position 2 sprite with different Z order? Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
float duration = 2.0f;
auto actionBy = RotateBy::create(duration / 2, Vec3(0, 90, 0));

backCard->runAction(RotateBy::create(0, Vec3(0, 90, 0)));
frontCard->runAction( Sequence::create(
                            actionBy,
                            CallFunc::create([backCard, actionBy](){backCard->runAction(actionBy);}),
                            nullptr)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 you need to simply do this : 

 CCRotateTo *act1= CCRotateTo::create(0.5, -180);
 CCRotateTo *act2= CCRotateTo::create(1.0, 180);

 CCSequence* act3 = CCSequence::create(act1,act2,NULL);

 sprite->runAction(act3);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should view https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4fJrMvZVhI

same with cocos2dx using `javascript`.

```js
 reveal: function (pIsFaceUp) {
    let self = this;
    let timeFlip =0.5;
    let callFunc = cc.callFunc(function () {
        self.cardBG.spriteFrame = pIsFaceUp ? self.texFrontBG : self.texBackBG;
        self.point.node.active = pIsFaceUp;
        self.suit.node.active = pIsFaceUp;
        self.mainPic.node.active = pIsFaceUp;
        if(!pIsFaceUp)
            self.node.skewY=135;
        else
            self.node.skewY=45;
    });
    if(!pIsFaceUp)
    {
        self.node.skewY=0;
        let action = cc.skewBy(timeFlip/2,0,45);
        let action2 = cc.skewTo(timeFlip/2,0,180);
        self.node.runAction(cc.sequence(action,callFunc,action2));
    }else
    {
        self.node.skewY=180;
        let action = cc.skewBy(timeFlip/2,0,-45);
        let action2 = cc.skewTo(timeFlip/2,0,0);
        self.node.runAction(cc.sequence(action,callFunc,action2));
    }

},
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 Sprites: spriteFront, spriteBack

**init (show spriteBack at first):** 
scale spriteFront to (0, 1) (scale X to 0, while keeping scale Y to 1)
scale spriteBack to (1, 1)

**flip animation:** 
scale spriteBack to (0, 1) 
after the animation, 
scale spriteFront to (1, 1)

```
float fDuration = 0.8f;

CCArray* pArray = CCArray::create();
pArray->addObject(CCScaleTo::create(fDuration/2, 0, 1));
pArray->addObject(CCTargetedAction::create(spriteFront, CCScaleTo::create(fDuration/2, 1)));
CCFiniteTimeAction* flipCardAnimation = CCSequence::create(pArray);

spriteBack->runAction(flipCardAnimation);
```

Comment: thanks for trying. But I want to see this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=te0Je0y4zU0 Your code does something different.